# What to look for in presentation framework to use with Meteor/Spacebars?

Tags: android, html, meteor, sass, spacebars

I am considering making a standalone app for a client — their request is that it run on Android tablets.  I was thinking that Meteor might be a good choice.  There seem to be a variety of frameworks out there — I've used Bootstrap 3 for projects, am intrigued by Jeet.gs — what issues do I need to take into account when choosing a presentation framework that will play nicely with Meteor?

Comment: Why the down vote?  As per Stack Overflow's own guidelines, the best way to ask a question that could be construed as an "opinion" question to is re-frame it and ask what one might look for in solving the problem oneself.  Thus I specifically _didn't_ ask what front end framework would be good with Meteor, but how I could best decide for myself.  Someone gave me a helpful link (below) — you, however, anonymously left a down vote.  Ah well, as has been asked, why is Stack Overflow so negative of late? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't personally worked with Meteor, however a Colleague of mine who has worked with it suggested this article:

http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-and-twitter-bootstrap---the-right-way

Hope this helps with your decision.